# If the first three columns of matrix A are linearly dependent, then are the first three column of a matrix AB also linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Full Question

**If the first three columns of matrix A are linearly dependent, then are the first three column of a matrix AB also linearly dependent for any matrix B (such that AB is defined)?**

AB refers to matrix multiplication.

This seems to be true for me intuitively but no matter how I think I can approach the "first three columns" part of the argument.

I also tried the contrapositive: If matrix AB first three columns are linearly independent are the first three rows of A (and presumably also B) linearly independent.

Comment: The result is false.  Let $B=0$ (or, make the first three columns of $B$ to be all zeros) for example.

Answer (score 1):

The result is not correct, Consider the following

$A$ = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 &1 & 0 & 0 \\2 &4 &6 & 0 &1 &0\\ 3 &6 &9 &0 &0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

The first 3 columns are linearly dependent

B = $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\0 &0 &0 \\ 0 &0 &0\\ 1 &0 &0 \\ 0 &1 & 0 \\ 0 &0 &1\end{bmatrix}$

$AB$ = $I$ which is linearly independent